# How to use pivot tags in open xml? Not able to parse the pivot tags in to the spreadsheet columns

Tags: xml, pivot, pivot-table, openxml, aspose

The following xml is using to apply pivots on custom tables. I tried it with a product tool aspose xml to xls converter .Why the tags are not resolving while parsing into xlsx.

I tried to apply open xml pivot tags on my dataset. I need to know is it possible to workout with open xml and aspose library? If yes how do we construct the request data for that? If there is any working xml with pivot tags please notify me?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<sh:pivotTableDefinition xmlns:sh="https://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" name="PivotTable1" cacheId="3"
          <sh:references count="2">
            <sh:reference field="14" count="1" selected="0">
              <sh:x v="0"/>
            </sh:reference>
            <sh:reference field="15" count="2" selected="0">
              <sh:x v="2"/>
              <sh:x v="3"/>
            </sh:reference>

</sh:pivotTableDefinition>

Comment: I am not sure about your requirements. Could you please elaborate your question/issue with more details and samples files. Also, give details about your scenario and your complete use-case. This way, one can understand your needs and scenario to assist you precisely.